# How to get objects referencing my object with Criteria

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hql

For example I have class A and B. Class C has foreign keys to A and B.
I have concrete instance of A and want to get all instances of B linked with this a. What can I do in hibernate? 
Criteria preferred if possible but any solutions will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<B> bList = session.createCriteria(C.class).add(Restrictions.eq("a",a)).setProjection(Projections.property("b")).list();
```